# ¿Reglas CSS No son Accesibles?

Tags: javascript, css, html5, eventos

estoy intentando aplicar un Evento 'Click' a un div en este caso quiero que sea el que me despliega la segunda botonera la cual la tengo oculta al cargar el sitio web. Quiero que solo se despliegue al darle Click al boton del menú. Éste es mi código al cual le quiero aplicar el evento con JavaScript.

```
<!--==============================
    =            BOTONERA            =
    ===============================-->
    <div class="container-fluid bg-light">
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="nav nav-justified py-2 nav-pills">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link font-weight-bold active">Inicio</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link font-weight-bold">Matemático</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link font-weight-bold">Gimnasio Bodytech</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link font-weight-bold">Spring Step</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link font-weight-bold">Postobón</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item" id="menu">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link font-weight-bold">
                        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--==============================
    =   BOTONERA MENU OCULTA       =
    ===============================-->
    <div class="container-fluid bg-light" id="menuOculto">
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="nav nav-justified py-2 nav-pills">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link font-weight-bold">Bancolombia</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link font-weight-bold">Numeros Pares</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link font-weight-bold">Frutas</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link font-weight-bold">Selección FCF</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Actualmente tengo el siguiente código en mi Script.js

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al realizar la prueba en mi Localhost, veo que tan carga la página, en la consola me carga un error repetido, el mismo se continua repitiendo cada vez que hago click en el boton del menú.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He consultado sobre el error pero no he encontrado una respuesta en español que me diga como solucionarlo, entiendo que se debe a una modificación realizada a partir de la versión 64 de Google Chrome, pero en realidad no sé como solucionarlo.

El evento de mostrar la botonera me funciona, mas sin embargo lo hace a partir del segundo Click, no al primero, y en cada click se repite ese error en consola.

Agradezco sus comentarios.

Actualización:
Este es el código natural html de mi página, donde relaciono como estoy haciendo la carga de los archivos...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>TALLER EVALUACION | WEB 1 | CESDE</title>

    <!-- Website Favicons -->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="vistas/img/icon.png" sizes="16x16">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="vistas/img/icon.png" sizes="32x32">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="vistas/img/icon.png" sizes="64x64">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Fonts Google -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Berkshire+Swash&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- CSS Styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vistas/css/estilos.css">

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Popper JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest FontAwesom version -->
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/29f215aa7a.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>

Aqui dentro va el código relacionado anteriormente.

    <!-- JS Script -->
    <script src="vistas/js/script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: acabo de realizar una prueba con tu código y si funciona, puedes dejar el html de tu pagina, para ver como estas cargando estilos

Comment: Saludos @EduardoJaramillo de acuerdo enseguida actualizo con el código html completo...

Comment: Según la imagen, los errores son ocasionados por una extensión de _Chrome_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Efectivamente al revisar las últimas extensiones instaladas en mi navegador, recordé que había instalado la **Extensión Emmet LiveStyle** que supuestamente es para trabajar con SublimeText para ver en vivo el código CSS en el navegador, fui la eliminé, refresqué la página y ya dejó de aparecer el error que me estaba arrojando, y efectivamente mi código funciona sin inconvenientes.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]